# Nesting New Fonts: Trying to Use Small Caps

Tags: fonts, xetex, nesting

Xelatex. I'm trying to use small caps with the Century Schoolbook font, which doesn't have them. 
I get "font not found" errors when I try to use system fonts that have small cap variants. That error seems to be quite a rabbit hole. So I thought I'd use a typeface that only has small caps, Alegreya SC. For my project, small caps have to be used both immediately before and after a decorative font (see picture.)

Here's a minimum example, which throws the error. It is possible to compile this by removing all references to small caps.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=5.5in:8.5in,DIV=12,BCOR=10mm,headings=small]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Bembo Std}

\fontspec[
SmallCapsFont=Alegreya SC,
 SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]{Bembo Std}

\begin{document}

\newfontfamily\myfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Century Schoolbook}
\newfontface\logo{Olde English}
\begingroup
\myfont

\begin{center} {\newfontfamily\myfont{Alegreya SC}In The}\\

{\textbf{\logo \huge Supreme Court of\\
the United States}}
\bigskip
\bigskip
{\newfontfamily\myfont{Alegreya SC} On Writ of Certiorari to the    United States\\
Court of Appeals for the Fifth Circuit}
\bigskip
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The error I'm getting is "\myfont already defined". So how do you nest a single instance of a new font inside an already defined new font? Is there another way to do this?

Another error message is, ""Package fontspec Warning: Opentype feature 'Letter=SmallCaps (smcp) not available for font 'Alegreya SC' with script 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.

[image: scourtcover]
[image: error messages]

Comment: `\\newfontfamily\myfont{Alegreya SC}` would force a newline then typeset the word `newfontfamily` presumably you had a single `\ ` but this declares a family (of the same name, but doesn't use it) declare your families with different names in the preamble then switch to the fonts via those names (not the fontspec declarations) where you need the font

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't entirely clear. What is the proper way to change the font on the fly? Presumably I should be able to change the font for a single symbol.

Comment: \\ was indeed a typo. Changing the declaration of Alegreya SC from "myfont" to "urfont" creates an error with the display (logo) font.